# Excel 10 Links from one workbook to another

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

Not sure if this has been asked, but I have a 2 part question.  First, when I copy a link from one workbook to another if there is no value in the source cell it will put a 0 in the end cell, how do I correct that so that it will leave the end cell blank if the source has no data (but may at a later time)?

Second, is it possible to create a link that will only copy a source only if a certain cell has data?  For example Cells A-I have data, but Cell J may have data input at a later date, when cell J has data I want to copy cells A-J to another workbook.

Comment: Can you show some example?

Comment: I'm not sure what example I can show other than what I stated before.   
Workbook 1 has 7 columns of data.  Columns 1-6 have data initially, but column 7 will only have data added at a later date.  Once the data is added to column 7 I want to have columns 1-7 copied to another workbook with the same formatting as in the original workbook.

Answer (score 0):

**First question:**

Go to file in your excel document and then to options. In options select the advanced tab. There should be a section called display options for this worksheet and there will be a check box checked with something like: display zero for cells with zero value. Uncheck that and your problem will be solved.

**Second question:**

To put in your cells in your other workbook:

```
=IF(ISBLANK('[otherworkbook.xlsx]Othersheet'!CellJ),"",'[otherworkbook.xlsx]
Othersheet'!CellA)
```

It is easiest when you use $-signs for J cell in the formula and don't use dollar signs for A cell, such that you can just drag the formula to all the cells you need.

Comment: The first answer was great and spot on.  However, in the second answer, not sure if I explained in my question.  I don't want to copy the cells unless a particular cell has data.

Comment: Sorry, misread the question. I think you will have to use formulas to achieve that, simply copying and pasting will not get you that functionality.

Comment: So do you want a formula answer, or do you want to keep searching for a simple copy and paste answer?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  The formula answer would be great, thank you.